# Shrinking JFrame causes drawings to disappear; Bullseye borders not showing up

Tags: java, jar, jframe

I'm supposed to be creating a `bullseye.jar` file. I'm having a few different issues.

1. My circles within the bullseye all need borders on them, but they aren't showing up. I figured the `g2.draw` would take care of that, but no dice.
2. When I run the program and drag the frame smaller, the bullseye sizes down as well. But I have to be sure that the smaller circles don't disappear (which they're doing when the bullseye shrinks).

I have two classes. The first is the component class and the second is the main.

Also here is a [link to an online IDE](https://ideone.com/0yMnHr).

```
/**
 *
 * @author joe
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class BullseyeComponent extends JComponent{

    int count = 0;

    @Override

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //make circle fill screen
        int radius = Math.min(this.getHeight(),this.getWidth()) / 2;


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius ));
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius));


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 25 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 25));


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 50 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 50));


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 75 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 75));

        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 100 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 100));


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 125 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 125));

        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 150 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 150));


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 175 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 175));

        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 200 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 200));


        g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2, radius - 225 ));
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2 , this.getHeight() / 2 , radius - 225));

    }
}

class Circle extends Ellipse2D.Double {

    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
        super(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }
}
```

```
/**
 *
 * @author joe
 */

import javax.swing.*;

public class BullseyeViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 550);
        frame.setTitle("Bullseye");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        BullseyeComponent component = new BullseyeComponent();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fix 1

The way you are drawing right now,

```
g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius ));
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius));
```

would overwrite the border (`draw` before `fill`). Replace it with

```
g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius));
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius ));
```

**Change the colors** (borders should have different colors otherwise they'd merge with outer circle) in an appropriate way.

---

### Fix 2

You are hard-coding the radius differences. That would make inner circles disappear even if you apply numerous hacks.

So to fix it, you have to scale the radius as well accordingly.

```
g2.fill(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius * 0.8));
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.draw(new Circle(this.getWidth()/ 2, this.getHeight() / 2, radius * 0.8));
```

Define **all radii as percentage of outer radius** and you should be good to go.

---

Hope this helps.
Good luck.